# Bounties for answers that were particularly useful

Tags: discussion, bounties

If I ask a question on StackOverflow, and find multiple answers to be especially pertinent and useful to my own work, is it appropriate to award a bounty to them?

Others may also find the information useful, but it would be hard to find given the context of the question.

Link: [How are the ntoh functions implemented under RHEL/GCC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17953371/how-are-the-ntoh-functions-implemented-under-rhel-gcc)

This is a question that I did not create with the intent to apply a bounty to, and I feel it *has* received sufficient attention.  I simply want to reward those who shared knowledge that I desperately needed right away.

Comment: Totally off topic, but I really like that "screenshot" you created (linked in your SO profile), you should publish it somewhere!

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd:  Screenshot? Linked in my profile?  Huh?

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/dOLkgVR.png maybe you put that long ago and forgot about it... :)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: Oh, yeah, haha.  I actually stole that from someone else, but it perfectly sums up my SO experience.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't start a bounty on that question yet, but once you can one of the reasons you can select from is:

> **Reward existing answer**
>
> One or more of the answers is exemplary and worthy of an additional bounty.

So yes, it is appropriate to use bounties this way.

Comment: Great, thanks.  I also saw in the FAQ that subsequent bounties must be at least double previous ones.  If I want to award, say, +100 to each of the three posted answers, is that possible?

Comment: @JohnDibling No, unfortunately I don't think it is. If you offer multiple bounties for the same question you have to keep increasing the value.

Comment: Well, it's not like I can't spare the rep.  I just don't want to 'snub' anyone.

Comment: You could probably award multiple bounties per person in a way that adds up to the same total. Would be a lot of rep to give out though

Comment: @JohnDibling You could just give them all 500.  ;)

Answer (score 2):

That's one of the accepted uses of bounties.

See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work?lq=1) for more info. It specifically mentions under "Can I award a bounty to an old answer?" that bounties can be used simply to increase the reward for a good post

Comment: I read that just before I posted.  Maybe I didn't read closely enough, but it didn't seem to address my question.

Comment: @JohnDibling Added more info on where it mentions that bounties are ok for this

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to start a bounty after someone has helped you get to the answer.  I have done so in the following [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/993780/assistance-with-openssl-blowfish-simple-example-inserting-garbage-characters).  If you feel that a user has gone above and beyond you can chose to take this course of action.